# Preprocesssor directive rule when +/- sign is put in MACROs

Tags: c

Consider the following code snippet.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define A -B
#define B -C
#define C 5

int main()
{
   printf("The value of A is %dn", A);
   return 0;
}
```

Now here the preprocessor first replaces the all A's in the code with '-B'.
Then it replaces all B's in the code with '-C'. So effectively the original A will now be '--C'.
Finally all the C's are replaced with 5. So A will now be --5. 
According to this logic the program should not compile.

But the output of the program is:

```
The value of A is 5
```

Please explain this.

Answer (score 0):

When macro substitution is done, it creates separate tokens, unless you use the token pasting operator `#`. So the result after all the macro expansions is

```
printf("The value of A is %dn", - - 5);
```

While `--5` is invalid, `- - 5` is OK. It negates `5` twice, and the negations cancel each other out, resulting in `5`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `gcc -E -o demo.i demo.c` to generate code after preprocessing. The bottom part of `demo.i` is:

```
int main()
{
   printf("The value of A is %dn", - -5);
   return 0;
}
```

We can see that A was actually replaced with `- -5`.

Then test following code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define A -B
#define B -C
#define C 5

int main()
{
   printf("The value of A is %dn", A);
   printf("The value of A is %dn", - - 6);
   return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
The value of A is 5
The value of A is 6
```

So, `gcc` can compile `- -5` correctly and work well.